# QR transformation with Householder transformation

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, numerical-optimization

It's a task i do to understand minimizing the error including the QR transformation with the help of Householder transformation. I think i really do something wrong but i dont get it running i hope you can help me.

Given the task to minimizing the error of

$$ A = \begin{pmatrix}
1 &1\\
1 & 0\\
1 & 1 \\
1 & 4
\end{pmatrix}
 b=\left[2,\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{2},5\right]^T
$$

So at first getting $A^TA = \begin{pmatrix} 4 & 6 \\ 6 &18 \end{pmatrix}$

after this calculate the householder vector $v_1=a_1+\alpha*e_1$.

$\alpha = sign(a_{1,1})*\lVert a_{1}\rVert = \sqrt{52} $

so

$$ v_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 4 \\ 6 \end{pmatrix} + \sqrt{52}*\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

BUT the problem is if i calculate Q ouf of this:

$$Q = I- \frac{2*v*v^T}{v^T*v} $$

I would be done. It would be $A^TA = QR$ with $ R= QA^TA$. (Sure i am resulting in some matix like $R=\begin{pmatrix} x &y\\0&z\end{pmatrix}$

But if i calculate that with Matlab i get incorrect results ($R=A^Tb$). Even the calculation of $v$ seems to be incorrect since it should ne just simple in fact that no calculater is allowed. If i simply calculate $A^TAx=A^Tb$ it's a simple calculation resulting in $x_1=\frac{7}{12} x_2=\frac{10}{9}$ which i dont get with the QR in any way.

Comment: You know that if (for whatever reason) you apply the Householder transformation to $A^TA$ (in the system $A^TAx=A^Tb$), you have to apply it also to the right-hand side ($QA^TAx=QA^Tb$)? (At least I've deduced this from "$R=A^Tb$ slammed to Matlab" at the end, whatever that means :D)

Comment: This actually solved the issue. Post it as answer and ill mark it. Thanks. And yes i should know that but just missed it. I really wonder about the task since it's hard to calculate without an calculator.

Comment: If this is a homework, are you sure you are asked to apply the Householder transformation to $A^TAx=A^Tb$ instead of directly to (the least squares problem) $Ax=b$?

Comment: It is no homework. Sure solving $A^TAx=A^Tb$ would be easy but they mention to solve it with QR AND householder transformation instead of solving it the "normal" way by LU or something like that. (It's training for the Exam... )

Comment: OK, so apply the Householder transformation to $A$ and $b$ directly (without forming the normal equations with $A^TA$). This is most likely what you are supposed to do. See also [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares_(mathematics)#Orthogonal_decomposition_methods).

Comment: How do i get the correct Householder matrix for that? Could you maybe explain the steps for this by this task as example? And sure do it as answer since i think that that would be the requested task. Id be thankfull for that

Comment: A major advantage of using QR is that it **avoids** solving the normal equations.

Comment: Right they mention this in the task that we shouldnt use the normal equations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments, this is probably what you're supposed to do.

To transform $A$ to the upper triangular form requires an application of two Householder transformations. Take
$$
Q_1=I-2\frac{v_1v_1^T}{v_1^Tv_1}=
\frac{1}{6}
\begin{bmatrix}
    -3  &  -3  &  -3  &  -3 \\
    -3  &   5  &  -1  &  -1 \\
    -3  &  -1  &   5  &  -1 \\
    -3  &  -1  &  -1  &   5 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\quad\text{with}\quad v_1=[3,1,1,1]^T.
$$
This gives
$$
Q_1^TA=\begin{bmatrix}
-2 &   -3 \\
 0 & -4/3 \\
 0 & -1/3 \\
 0 &  8/3
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Next, take
$$
Q_2=I-2\frac{v_2v_2^T}{v_2^Tv_2}
=\frac{1}{117}\begin{bmatrix}
       117 &   0 &   0 &   0 \\
         0 & -52 & -13 & 104 \\
         0 & -13 & 116 &   8 \\
         0 & 104 &   8 &  53 
\end{bmatrix}
\quad\text{with}\quad v_2=[0,-13/3,-1/3,8/3]^T
$$
to get
$$
R:=Q^TA:=Q_2^TQ_1^TA=
\begin{bmatrix}
 -2 & -3 \\
  0 &  3 \\
  0 &  0 \\
  0 &  0 
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Apply $Q^T$ to $b$ to get
$$
Q^Tb=
\begin{bmatrix}
-9/2 \\
   10/3 \\
 -11/39 \\
 -19/78
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Hence, the least squares problem $Ax=b$ is equivalent to the least squares problem
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
 -2 & -3 \\
  0 &  3 \\
  0 &  0 \\
  0 &  0 
\end{bmatrix}x
=
\begin{bmatrix}
-9/2 \\
   10/3 \\
 -11/39 \\
 -19/78
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
The residual 2-norm is minimal, if the first two components of the residual vector are zero, that is,
the least squares solution is given by the solution of
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
 -2 & -3 \\
  0 &  3
\end{bmatrix}x
=
\begin{bmatrix}
-9/2 \\
   10/3
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Comment: Thanks alot for the effort and for your time! I started that but ran into some troubles and wasnt sure anymore

Comment: You're welcome! Although a lot of credit goes also to the symbolic toolbox :)

Comment: Hey great answer! But just a point: to calculate Q2 we need v2. And v2 is the sign of the most upper left element (here sign(-2)) multiplicated with the 2nd norm of the vektor that we are considerating now, which is (-4/3 -1/3 8/3)transp. --> And this gives me: v2 = (-13/3 -1/3 8/3)transp.  So where do you have the 0 as first element of this vector please? How are you getting (0 -13/3 -1/3 8/3) for v2? It would be really helpful, if you could answer this! Thank you in advance!!

Comment: @ZelelB But $Q_2^T$ is not applied on a sub-matrix of $A$ but on the *whole* matrix so it must be $4\times 4$ and $v_2$ must be so that $Q_2^T$ does not alter the first row. Hence its first component is zero.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel So you calculate it normally, you get v2 = (-13/3 -1/3 8/3)transp, and then you calculate Q2 (with that v2 as a (3x1) vector) which gonna be (3x3)-matrix, then you calculate Q2t*A' which gonna be (3x3) * (3*1) = (3x1) Vektor, which is (3 0 0)trans. and you just put it in the down let corner of the matrix instead of A'? PS: A' = (-4/3 -1/3 8/3)transp.  That means, you do all the calculations with v2 being a (3x1) vector, and then you just add a 0 at the end on top? Or you do the calculations with that 0 as first element in v2?

Comment: @ZelelB It's just simplification of notation.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel Would you please add Q1 and Q2 (the mid-calculations) to the answer? Because you're just writing the result or the formula, but not the concrete matrix, and it would be really really helpful! Thanks a lot in advance?

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel Wow thx a lot man!!! I got the same results, but I am calculating with Q1 and Q2 not Q1t and Q2t (at least till calculating R, didn't read the rest yet). Is it a problem? Or as they are orthoghonal, I can use Q1 & Q2 instead of Q1t, Q2t?

Comment: @ZelelB The Householder matrices are symmetric, so...

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel Okay. But at the end, to calculate Q (or Qt) we still have to multiply Q1 with Q2, to get to Q*b. Right? Which in this specific example would be a (4x4) * (4x4) matrix multiplication. Isn't that so expensive as a calculation? Or is there a way to get Q without this huge multiplication?

Comment: You never actually need to compute the $Q$ matrices. The matrix-vector product $(I-\beta vv^T)x$ you compute as $x-\beta v(v^Tx)$, that is one scalar product and a linear combination.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel but when you say Qt*b = (−9/2, 10/3, −11/39, −19/78) How you got these values? Didn't you calculated Qt and then multiplied it by vector b? Thus to get Qt, you multiply Q2*Q1? Or how is it?

Comment: @ZelelB You do not need the compute $Q$ explicitly. LutzL just explained that $Qx=x-2(v^Tx/v^Tv)v$.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel sorry didn't get it though.. And this would be the last question please. Sorry to bother. Just how to concretely calculate it? How to do the calculation for example in this very specific case with the concrete values to get that values for Qt*b?

Comment: Please if someone could help with this, it would be really great! I am having an exam on numerical mathematics which will be really important! And this last question (above comment) to answer is so important for me! Thank you in advance

Comment: @ZeleIB You do not need to compute any $Q$ explicitly. It is given by a certain formula, so if you want to compute a product $Qz$ a vector  $z$ just substitute that formula for $Q$ in the expression. Also note that if $M=xy^T$, where $x$ and $y$ are vectors, then $Mz=(xy^T)z=x(y^Tz)=(y^Tz)x$.

Comment: Okay got it finally! 
1) Correct me please if I'm wrong: So I basically multiply Q1 not just with A, but on both sides (with b also), and then when I compute Q2, I multiply it also not just with (Q1*A) on the LHS, but with (Q1*b') on the RHS. (did that and got the result above)
2) Last question: How much is the residuum for this Least-Squares-Problem? Is it sqrt( (−11/39)^2 + (−19/78)^2 ) ? 
3) If not how to calculate it? Thank you lot! These were the very last  questions, and sorry for bothering!

Comment: @ZeleIB Ad 1) Yes, you need of course to transform both sides of the equation. Ad 2) Yes, when a LS problem gets orthogonally transformed to the form $\begin{bmatrix}R\\0\end{bmatrix}x=\begin{bmatrix}c_1\\c_2\end{bmatrix}$ with a nonsingular $R$, the norm of the residual is the norm of $c_2$ because $Rx=c_1$ so the first component of the residual vector is zero.

Comment: Great! Thank you so much!!